# Auto update option in Play! framework

Tags: playframework

How do I add an option for auto-update feature (like on Youtube and Twitter) using the play framework?

Specifically, if I was making a Stackoverflow clone, I'd want new questions to show up without having to refresh the page. Or, when viewing a question, new answers get added to the list without refreshing the entire page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions, both possible without problems in Play!

1. Use AJAX to send request for some period of time and check if there are new events for displayed page and the use ie. jQuery to update values of required eleements.
2. StackOverflow as I can see uses `websockets` for updating vote counters, informing about edits, etc. It's reaaaaly powerful feature, but keep in mind that older browser can have some problems with it.

Comment: You're welcome, you can even mark the question as `answered` ;) BTW SO's performance is really impressive job to reproduce, I'd love to gain such!